# refer to a variable which is not in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, scope

I have a structure like this :

```
{
    ....
    initComponent : function () {
        ....
        this.appCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            ....
            listeners : {
                // Use 'data' here
            }
        }
    },
    load : function () {
        var data = ....
    }
}
```

I wish to use the data where I have mentioned but the '`data is undefined`' error keeps on popping. Kindly advice how do I access the 'data' variable in the place where I have specified.

Comment: `data` is local to the function. Why not define it outside the function?

Comment: If I declare it inside initComponent then it won't be accessible to load. I can't declare it outside both initComponent and load since in extjs I need to have a key:value type structure. I can only use javascript inside a function.

Comment: do you have any shared 'context' accessible from both initComponent and load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version you are working with. But you should be able to add a config property - and Ext will then automatically generate getters and setters for this config. Just make sure the load method has set the data before trying to access it in your listener.

```
{
    config: {
        data: null
    }
    ....
    initComponent : function () {
        var me = this;
        ....
        this.appCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            ....
            listeners : {
                ....me.getData(); // returns the data if it has been set already
            }
        }
    },
    load : function () {
        var me = this;
        me.setData(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data : null,
initComponent : function () {
    var me = this;
    this.appCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        ....
        listeners : {
            // Use 'data' here
            me.data = "FOO"
        }
    }
},
load : function () {
    this.data = ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `vars` object inside your object (to not expose it to the global scope), that will hold your variables.

```
{
    vars : {
        data : null
    },

    initComponent : function () {
        var self = this;
        this.appCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            listeners : {
                alert(self.vars.data);
            }
        }
    },

    load : function () {
        this.vars.data = 'Hello';
        this.initComponent();
    }
}
```